# How can I make the code loop from the beginning of the calculation (input height and weight)? I tried to use def main but I may used it wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
A="Welcome"
B="Done by: "Name"
C="Class: "Class"
D="IT Final project - CP2"
E="A program that calculates the BMI and describes it as underweight, healthy, overweight, severly overweight, obese, severly obese"
print(A)
print(B)
print(C)
print(D)
print(E)
Height=input("Enter height in meters")
Height=float(Height)
Weight=input("Enter weight in kg")
Weight=float(Weight)
BMI=(Weight/Height**2)
if BMI <= 18.4:
    print(BMI,"You are underweight")
elif BMI <= 24.9:
    print(BMI,"You are healthy")
elif BMI <= 29.9:
    print(BMI,"You are overweight")
elif BMI <= 34.9:
    print(BMI,"You are severly overweight")
elif BMI <= 39.9:
    print(BMI,"You are obese")
elif BMI > 39.9:
    print(BMI,"You are severly overweight")
Repeat=input("Do you want to make a new calculation?(Yes/No)")
if "No":
    print("Done")
    exit()
elif: "yes":
```

What should I add here or anywhere else in the code?

Comment: the jmkkkkkkkkkkkkk is because i needed to write something to post the question.

Comment: Please search online for a Python tutorial and read up on the looping constructs.

Answer (score 0):

So,
Your code is a little messed up at the start, lemme fix it real quickly
You shall remove the wrong placed (")

```py
A="Welcome"
B="Done by: (Name) Jhon Smith"
C="Class: (Class) AB"
D="IT Final project - CP2"
E="A program that calculates the BMI and describes it as underweight, healthy, overweight, severly overweight, obese, severly obese"
```

Now that that's done, the main question.

You need to use while loops, while keeps running until the condition is false. In this case we want it to loop till the user types no.
So you will need to wrap your code with `while 1:`
Here it is: (Plus some edits to make the code work)

````py
A="Welcome"
B="Done by: Name"
C="Class: Class"
D="IT Final project - CP2"
E="A program that calculates the BMI and describes it as underweight, healthy, overweight, severly overweight, obese, severly obese"
print(A)
print(B)
print(C)
print(D)
print(E)



while 1:
  try:
    height = float(input("Enter height in meters: "))
    if height == 0:
      print("Error, input not valid")
      continue
  except Exception:
    print("Error, input not valid")
    continue
  try:
    weight = float(input("Enter weight in kg: "))
    if weight == 0:
      print("Error, input not valid")
      continue
  except Exception:
    print("Error, input not valid")
    continue
  
  bmi = (weight/height**2)
  
  if bmi <= 18.4:
    print(bmi, "You are underweight!")
  elif bmi <= 24.9:
    print(bmi, "You are healthy!")
  elif bmi <= 29.9:
    print(bmi, "You are overweight.")
  elif bmi <= 34.9:
    print(bmi, "You are severly overweight.")
  elif bmi <= 39.9:
    print(bmi, "You are obese.\nYou are severly overweight.")
  
  while 1:
    end = input("Repeat? (Yes/No): ")
    if end.lower() == "yes":
      break
    elif end.lower() == "no":
      print("Done.")
      exit()
    else:
      print("Please type Yes/No")
```
This works perfect, if you need any help, post a comment!

PS: Press the check mark beside this answer to mark it as "helpful" / accept answer
````